# How to extract list of lists from a csv-file with python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv-file resembling basically this structure (1 column, 2 rows):

| participant,Date and Time,yadayada,... |
| --- |
| {'Name': ...},...,"[[1, 1, 1, 0],[1, 0, 1, 1]]", |

What I want to do is to retrieve only the list of lists cornered by the quotation marks.

Comment: You should be able to do something like: `import json; with open("file.csv", "r") as f: data = json.load(f.read())`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(
        """participant,a,b,c,colname\n"""
        """{'Name': 'asdf'},3,5,6,"[[1, 1, 1, 0],[1, 0, 1, 1]]"\n"""
    )

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
colname = 'colname'

res = []
for sublist in df.loc[0, colname][2:-2].split('],['):
    res.append([int(item) for item in sublist.split(', ')])
print(l)
```

prints

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Remarks: Here I assume that there is only one row in the data, and that the column you intend to access is stored in the variable `colname`.